# why python is throwing attribute attribute error

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following unit test written in python,When i try to run this code, i am getting an attribute error in the console that 
**AttributeError: 'testLogin' object has no attribute 'lp'** I am very new to python and i would like to get some insight on this attribute issue

Is there any issues that needs to be fixed. Your help us highly recommended.

```
from utilities.teststatus import TestStatus as ts
import unittest
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("oneTimeSetup", "setUp")
class testLogin(unittest.TestCase):

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self,oneTimeSetup):
        self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
    @pytest.mark.order1
    def test_validLogin(self):
        self.lp.login("test@email.com", "abcabc")
        userIcon = self.lp.verifyLoginSuccessful()
        title = self.lp.verifyPageTitle()
        ts.markFinal(title,"Login not successful")
        assert userIcon == True
```

When i try to run this unittest, i am getting the error as **AttributeError: 'testLogin' object has no attribute 'lp'**

Can some one please help to fix it ?

Comment: Looks like `classSetup` is not run for some reason. Maybe you are running `unittest` instead of `pytest`? You shouldn't mix pytest and unittest - there is no reason to derive from `unittest.TestCase` if you are using `pytest` (even if it would work), and `unittest` knows nothing about `pytest`.

Comment: Thanks.. That helped. I was running the tests as unitTests. Now i changed the configurations to Pytest  and it runs.. Thanks